# Challenges on publishing knowledge Translated article

Tags: approval-process, lightning-knowledge

We have created approval process in Lightning on knowledge object, where Internal user will assign article to translators. Then translators will send article to Internal user for review and approval.

Currently Internal users are able to approve the translated records. But Internal users are unable to publish the translated records which is already approved.

Salesforce Classic Error:

> The Translation was not published because of a conflict.

Salesforce Lightning error:

> You can't perform this action. Be sure action is valid for the current state of the article.

Let us know if you have any ideas to overcome from this scenario.

Comment: do they have the profile permission to publish translations?

Comment: Yes. They have permission for publishing article but admin also unable to publish the translated article which is approved..

Comment: It's important to note there's two separate profile permissions for Lightning knowledge: one for articles and the other for translations.

Comment: @ Kris, We have already provided the permission "publish-articles" and " publish Translation-article" access on profile level but still we are getting this error while publishing translated article which is approved.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SFSE

There is a somewhat related [Salesforce known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YXkAAM) about the conflict error which states the following:

> When you translate an article the url name is copied over to the destination language. URL Name has to be unique per language so when you try to translate an article into a language where its url name already taken it gets a conflict.

The issue is still in review but the workaround suggested is to rename article URL name to resolve conflict error.

Try to see if you can add a Field Update in approval action of the approval process to rename the article URL name (by appending some unique field for example) so that it prevents the conflict.

Comment: Hi, we have also tried by appending URL name,title with unique field but still we are unable to publish the translated article.

Comment: @Santhosh According to this [post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DmilQAC) the user publishing the article must also have a role. Can you cross check if the role is missing on the user ?

Comment: Yes. User has role and even admin is unable to publish the article which is approved.

Comment: @Santhosh If not already done, then log a case with salesforce support to have their feedback